# Nexus 6P - Fingerprint unlock setup

Tags: security, google, nexus-6p

I would like to setup fingerprint unlock on my Nexus 6P. I believe I have it setup correctly, but when I go to unlock the phone by putting my finger on the sensor, it vibrates once then makes me put in my pattern to unlock the phone. Isn't there a way to unlock with just the fingerprint and not have to do the pattern also?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps ! [Setting up the finger print on nexus devices](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiZ1bCB8vDNAhVLwI8KHWr0C4UQFggdMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fnexus%2Fanswer%2F6285273%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNGwe-vCSnatC0aopcMqKqjUqKaCgw&sig2=RbG-yP78XuQSqWW3wAUNlg&bvm=bv.126993452,d.c2I)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set up your fingerprints again, making sure to cover as much of your finger as possible. You need to do the tip, sides and center of the tip of your finger in order for it to be able to properly identify your finger. If you don't train it properly then it won't be able to reliably identify your fingerprint so will vibrate to let you know it hasn't read it properly.

The more you are able to successfully unlock your phone the better the detection gets as it learns with each unlock.

If you have successfully set taught your device your fingerprint(s) the you should be able to unlock it with either your fingerprint or the pattern. It should not require both to unlock (although both do need to be configured so that you have a backup option if your fingerprint isn't recognised)

Comment: Thanks, I tried deleting all the fingerprints and setting them up again, but nothing changed. It does recognize my fingerprint because I can use it to open unlock certain apps. When I go to unlock the screen, I don't see the fingerprint icon at the bottom - just the padlock, and it makes me do the pattern even with a correct fingerprint.

Comment: I see the same here, @billyswifty – were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

You got both finger print and pattern turned on. just shut off pattern

Comment: It is required to have a backup option enabled when using a fingerprint so having a pattern as well as fingerprint is not a problem.